# ¿Cómo puedo devolver datos de una promesa?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Trabajo con **NodeJS**. He hecho una base de datos en **SQLite** (no confundir con **SQLite3**), y quiero comprobar si un usuario tiene cierto rango.

> msg.member.roles.has(rows.moderator);

Sin embargo, me enfrento a un nuevo problema, devolver el valor fuera de la promesa. El código es el siguiente:

```
var sql = require('sqlite');
bot.elevation = function(msg) {
  let permlvl = 0;
  sql.open('guildconfig.db').then(() => {
    sql.get(`SELECT * FROM config WHERE id = '${msg.guild.id}'`).then(rows => {
      if (!rows) {
        sql.run('INSERT INTO config (id) VALUES (?)', [`${msg.guild.id}`]);
        if (msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) permlvl = 1;
        if (msg.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) permlvl = 2;
      } else {
        if (msg.member.roles.has(rows.moderator)) permlvl = 1;
        if (msg.member.roles.has(rows.administrator)) permlvl = 2;
        // return permlvl;
      }
    })
  });
  if (msg.author.id === msg.guild.owner.id) permlvl = 3;
  if (msg.author.id === '242043489611808769') permlvl = 10;
  return permlvl;
};
```

Lo que quiero hacer es devolver el valor de `permlvl` que está dentro del `.then`, ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Tanto sqlite como sqlite3 son asincronos, para devolver el valor de una promesa toca con otra promesa o con un callback

Comment: Por lo que me dijeron, SQLite no trabaja nunca con callbacks.

Comment: el callback lo tendria que pasar en su funcion elevation como parametro y llamarlo cuando tenga el resultado de la promesa

Comment: Olvidé incluir la variable `sql`, perdón. Ya lo he editado

Comment: Sólo una, que se acercó muchísimo, aunque opté por un sistema muchísimo más rápido e eficiente, [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43383/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-hacer-un-query-a-cada-fila-de-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `chaining` de promesas, deberías poder hacerlo así:

```
var sql = require('sqlite');
bot.elevation = function (msg) {

  if (msg.author.id === msg.guild.owner.id) {
    return Promise.resolve(3);
  }

  if (msg.author.id === '242043489611808769') {
    return Promise.resolve(10);
  }

  // Return a Promise
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => sql.open('guildconfig.db', { Promise }))
    .then(() => sql.get('SELECT * FROM config WHERE id = ?', msg.guild.id))
    .then(rows => {
      let permlvl;

      if (!rows) {
        sql.run('INSERT INTO config (id) VALUES (?)', msg.guild.id);
        if (msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
          permlvl = 1;
        }
        else if (msg.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
          permlvl = 2;
        }
      } else  if (msg.member.roles.has(rows.moderator)) {
        permlvl = 1;
      }
      else if (msg.member.roles.has(rows.administrator)) {
          permlvl = 2;
      }

      return permlvl;
    });
};
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
bot.elevation(msg)
  .then(lvl => { console.log(lvl); });
```

Comment: Tengo un problema, la base de datos permanece cerrada, por lo tanto, `rows` es siempre undefined.

Comment: @AntonioRoman, me llama la atención tu comentario ya que si así fuera entonces la `promise` que devuelve `sql.open`, debería ser rechazada (`reject`) y no debería pasar por ninguno de los `then`'s

Comment: @AntonioRoman, he actualizado mi respuesta utilizando la sintaxis propuesta en la [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite#appjs-nodejsexpress)

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos formas sin usar callbacks:

- Usando promise chaining
- Usando async/await

**Promise chaining**

Ésta técnica consiste en encadenar promesas, de tal modo que un valor pueda seguir mutando a través de éstas.

```
bot.elevation = function (msg) {
  return sql.open('guildconfig.db')
    .then(() => {
      return sql.get(...)
    })
    .then(rows => {
      ... // revisar permisos
      return permlvl;
    });
};
```

Así, cuando llames a `bot#elevation` obtendrás una nueva promesa con el valor de la última promesa anidada.

**Async/Await**

Ésta es la nueva forma para tratar con programación asíncrona y promesas en general. Por medio de `await` podemos "esperar" a que una promesa termine su ejecución.

> Mediante async/await la programación sigue siendo asíncrona, lo único que cambia es la manera de hacerla. Mediante async/await se puede escribir código asíncrono como si fuese asíncrono

```
bot.elevation = async function (msg) {
  await sql.open('guildconfig.db');
  let rows = await sql.get(...);
  let permlvl;

  if (!rows) {
    await sql.run(...);
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
  return permlvl;
}
```

Y lo usarías de ésta forma:

```
(async () => {
  let permlvl = await bot.elevation({ ... });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

El codigo quedaria algo asi, tambien se de un modulo en nodejs que hace las consultas sincronicas en sqlite https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite-sync

```
bot.elevation = function(msg, callback) {
  let permlvl = 0;
  sql.open('guildconfig.db').then(() => {
    sql.get(`SELECT * FROM config WHERE id = '${msg.guild.id}'`).then(rows => {
      if (!rows) {
        sql.run('INSERT INTO config (id) VALUES (?)', [`${msg.guild.id}`]);
        if (msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) permlvl = 1;
        if (msg.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) permlvl = 2;
      } else {
        if (msg.member.roles.has(rows.moderator)) permlvl = 1;
        if (msg.member.roles.has(rows.administrator)) permlvl = 2;
      }
      if (msg.author.id === msg.guild.owner.id) permlvl = 3;
      if (msg.author.id === '242043489611808769') permlvl = 10;
      callback(permlvl);
    });
  });
  // return permlvl;
};

bot.elevation(msg, function(permlvl){
    console.log(permlvl);
});
```

Comment: Usar consultas *sincrónicas* con Node ... te cepillas lo bueno que tiene :-(

Comment: Tienes razon @Trauma pero es lo que esta buscando quien esta preguntando, yo me decantaria por usar una promesa o un callback

Comment: Ya, @Lcop, no es contra tu respuesta, que es **muy correcta**. Era solo mi opinión. Yo usaría *callbacks*, las promesas ... aún no les encontré la ventaja, aparte de su *supuesta* claridad.

Comment: La ventaja de las promesas (ES6) es que son completamente asíncronas, y están para reemplazar a los callbacks (ES5). Una solución (según me contó alguien) para todo mi enredo es usar async (ES7), pero claro, no sé muy claro cómo hacerlo, y siguen siendo promesas.

Comment: @Lcop la razón por la que estoy usando **sqlite** y no **sqlite3** es porque ésta primera trabaja con Promises y no con callbacks, haciendo su trabajo muchísimo más eficiente en cuanto asincronía. Busco una respuesta que me permita seguir usando **sqlite** o Javascript ES6. (Aunque no me vendría nada mal hacerlo en Js ES7 y usar async, que son una solución bastante más fácil, pero no lo he usado nunca, y mi experiencia en ES7 es nula)

Edit: http://pastebin.com/6RLWjiXc < solución en ES7, pero tendría que adaptarlo, ya que se usa en un evento y no en una función.

Comment: @AntonioRoman si lo queria basar en promesas lo correcto es que hubiera retornado una promesa y no un retorno. ese era el punto principal de correccion, lo importante es que se haya podido ayudar

Comment: Sin entrar en debate, sigo sin verle utilidad a las promesas. Se limitan a *enmascarar* los callbacks, pero, por debajo, siguen siendo eso, callbacks. No les veo mucho sentido. **Por diseño**, Javascript fué, es, y será, siempre asíncrono. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: @Trauma La principal y gran ventaja es el encadenamiento (chain) de promesas. El poder escribir patrones como `.then(...).then(...).then(...).catch(...).then(...)`, para mí mejora la lectura del código y manejo de errores.

Answer (score 0):

Por tu pregunta y posteriores discusiones que leo en las demás respuestas veo que parten de un concepto muy básico que aun no tienen claro, **Javascript es un lenguaje funcional asíncrono**, cualquier operación I/O en javascript va a ser siempre asíncrono, eso no depende de la base de datos o API que utilicen para realizar estas operaciones, esa es la naturaleza del lenguaje y todos sus API siempre se va a manejar con callbacks o promises.

Sqlite, Sqlite3, Mongo, Redis, ES, Postgres y demás BD habidas y por haber **no son asíncronos**, son solo bases de datos, si quieres acceder a ellos utilizando Java por ejemplo entonces todas las llamadas I/O que Java realice a estas bases de datos van a ser síncronas, bloqueantes e imperativas.

Por el contrario si utilizan Javascript entonces los API's para acceder a las mismas bases de datos van a ser siempre asíncronas y funcionales por ende no bloqueantes.

Para lidiar con la ejecución asíncrona en Javascript tienes siempre 2 modelos, callbacks y promises.

En Javascript tu puedes pasar una función como parámetro o valor, porque las funciones en Javascript son objetos de primer orden, esto es lo que te permite pasar código como parámetro, dicho código puede ser ejecutado en otro punto de la aplicación, mientras que la secuencia de ejecución principal puede continuar a las siguientes instrucciones esta característica es la que te permite implementar los callbacks.

Tanto callbacks como promises son asíncronos, es algo ineludible incluso si utilizas async/await a la final vas a tener que lidiar con ejecución asíncrona, para lidiar con la ejecución del del código asíncrono y ejecutar de manera serial código asíncrono tienes dos opciones:

- anidamiento en el caso de callbacks
- y promise chaining en el caso de
  promises

No colocare código especifico de uso del API de SQLite ya que lo importante es el concepto, esto se aplica en todas las librerias que encuentres en Javascript

Esto es anidamiento de callbacks

```
SQliteDAO.getCliente(1, function(error, cliente){
  if(error){
    throw 'Error al obtener el cliente:' + error.msg;
  } else {
    SQliteDAO.getPermisos(cliente.id, function(error, permisos){
      if(error){
        throw 'Error al obtener permisos:' + error.msg;
      } else {
        permisos.forEach(function(permiso){
        console.log('Permiso: ' + permiso);
      })
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Nota que para poder ejecutar una instrucción asíncrona luego de otra instrucción asíncrona debo anidar los callbacks que se ejecutan al finalizar cada operación, para de esa manera serializar todas las operaciones.

También nota como al anidar todos los callbacks el código se vuelve cada vez mas difícil de leer y el control de errores se los debe en cada callback.

Ahora con promises esto seria así.

```
SQLiteDAO.getCliente(1)
  .then(cliente => return SQLiteDAO.getPermisos(cliente.id))
  .then(permisos => permisos.forEach(permiso => console.log('Permiso: ' + permiso)))
  .fail(error => console.log('Error: ' + error.msg));
```

Con promises haces lo mismo, controlas el flujo de ejecución de codigo asíncrono pero no usas anidamiento sino method chaining (una técnica que no es invento de promises), los promises siempre retornan un valor que puede ser un nuevo promise o el valor con el resultado final y tambien puede retornar un error, una ventaja es que el error se puede propagar en toda el chain y capturarlo al final del chain por esta razón no necesitas capturar el error luego de cada ejecución de un promise intermedio y puedes capturarlo al final, esa es una ventaja de method chaining.

Con promises el código es mas natural, fácil de leer y te sirve para el mismo propósito que los callbacks anidados pero su uso es mas sencillo, imagina tener que hacer 10 llamadas asíncronas anidando 10 callbacks a diferencia de encadenar los promises y capturar cualquier error al final.

Como ves son dos maneras diferentes de hacer lo mismo, hay muchos mas detalles técnicos de la implementación de los promises por ejemplo internamente utilizan callbacks que siempre reciben dos parámetros, 'error' y 'respuesta' function(err, data), la mayoria de API's antiguas que no utilizan promises sino callbacks utilizan callbacks de la forma function(err, data), esto permite que esos mismos API's puedan ser transformados a promises, lo puedes ver [aquí](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#the-beginning).

Estos dos patrones vas a encontrar siempre en Javascript, ahora con la mejora de async/await en el caso de promises pero siempre vas a estar lidiando con código asíncrono y todas las API's que utilices te ofrecerán uno o ambas técnicas de programación.

Comment: Respecto al segundo párrafo que usted ha escrito, SQLite puede funcionar de manera completamente asíncrona, http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous

Comment: Estas refiriéndote al funcionamiento interno de la base no al API con el que te comunicas con la base en JavaScript, desde JavaScript todos los API para operaciones I/O son asíncronos no importa que implementación interna tenga la base de datos, sigue sin estar claro...