# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un query a cada fila de SQLite?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sqlite, collectionjs

Trabajo en NodeJS, necesito crear una colección de datos de todas las entradas existentes en una determinada tabla, y para eso necesito algo como un `forEach`.

Por el momento, tengo el siguiente código:

```
var sql = require('sqlite');
bot.configs = new Discord.Collection();
sql.open('guildconfig.db').then(() => {
  sql.get(`SELECT * FROM config`).then(rows => {
    bot.configs.set(rows.ID, rows);
  });
});
```

(Quité el `WHERE ID '${msg.guild.id}'` para ver si de esa manera hacía un forEach, pero no lo hace).

Pero cuando ejecuto `bot.configs`, obtengo la siguiente colección:

> Collection { '244584926559731713' => [Object] }

La razón por la que necesito el equivalente al `forEach` es porque necesito crear un objeto por cada entrada que existe en la base de datos, ligada a su ID, (en la salida, `244584926559731713` es la propiedad `ID` del objeto).

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: No domino NodeJS, pero parece que tu código se está ejecutando una vez por cada fila, y tu problema estaría en la asignación quizás, que estás sobreescribiendo el mismo objeto. De todas formas, lo que estás buscando (mapear filas con objetos), se llama `object persistance` (o `persistent class`). Seguro que hay librerías que implementen `object persistance` que hagan lo que buscas en una sola línea (aparte de indicar qué clase/protitpo corresponde a qué tabla, y qué campo a qué columna, y el resto lo hace la librería).

Comment: Debería ejecutarse en cada fila, pero no lo hace, he hecho `console.log(rows)` y sólo muestra una.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres obtener **todos** los registros entonces deberías usar [`.all()`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseallsql-param--callback), ya que [`.get()`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databasegetsql-param--callback) solo devuelve el primer registro.

Así por ejemplo:

```
var sql = require('sqlite');
bot.configs = new Discord.Collection();
sql.open('guildconfig.db').then(() => {
  sql.all('SELECT * FROM config').then(rows => {
    rows.forEach(row => {
      bot.configs.set(row.ID, row);
    });
  });
});
```